# Android: Back button to hide edit text then kill activity

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyevent

I'm trying to hide an edit text when the back button is pressed, and then when the back button is pressed again the activity is closed. At the moment when the back button is pressed the edit text is hidden and the activity is closed at the same time. How can I close the activity on the second press of the back button after the edit text has been hidden? Here is my code:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){

    if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        if(myFilter.isShown()){
            myFilter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else if(!myFilter.isShown()){
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
return true;
```

}

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't it be enough to return false by default and true right after changing the visibility to GONE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if(myFilter.isShown()){
            myFilter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Your welcome! This way you block the default functionality when you need to.